# How to have Doxygen skip the mention to Base class in the Derived method signatures?

Tags: c++, inheritance, documentation, doxygen

I have the following classes

```cpp
namespace detail{
   template<class T>
   class Base{
      /// @brief A foo method
      void foo(){}
   };
}
/// @brief A derived class
template<class T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {};
```

I have Doxygen 1.9.5 and the following CMake config:

```
  set(DOXYGEN_GENERATE_TREEVIEW YES)
  set(DOXYGEN_HTML_HEADER "header.html")
  set(DOXYGEN_COLLABORATION_GRAPH NO)
  set(DOXYGEN_CLASS_GRAPH NO)
  set(DOXYGEN_EXTRACT_PRIVATE NO)
  #set(DOXYGEN_EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS "detail")
  set(DOXYGEN_EXTRACT_ALL NO)
  set(DOXYGEN_INHERIT_DOCS YES)
  set(DOXYGEN_INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB YES)
  set(DOXYGEN_USE_MATHJAX YES)
  set(DOXYGEN_WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED NO)
  set(DOXYGEN_HTML_COLORSTYLE LIGHT)
  set(DOXYGEN_LAYOUT_FILE "DoxygenLayout.xml")
  set(DOXYGEN_FULL_PATH_NAME YES)
  set(DOXYGEN_STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH "../src/include")
```

And in the detailed method description of `Derived`, all inherited functions show the scope resolution of the base, that is `void detail::Base<T>::foo()`.

This is inconvenient because in my real case several nested namespaces and template parameters make the complete function definition lengthy. Is there a way to have Doxygen strip the signature of the methods in Derived from the mention to the base method ?

Comment: What would you like to see instead of the `void detail::Base<T>::foo()`?

Comment: Just `foo()` ? As if it was a plain, non-inherited member function :) Is it possible?

Comment: Did you have a look at the setting `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES`?